# How to add a fixed marker on a Mapbox map? (React)

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I want to add a fixed marker to a Mapbox map. The marker should always be centered.

[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNQxB.png)

I did this workaround.

```
#map {

 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

#marker {
 display:block; 
 position:absolute;
 top:50vh;
 left:50vw;
 z-index:100;
 text-align:center;
}
```

I'm looking for something out of the (Map)box to avoid the workaround.

Thank you!

Comment: It works by using a marker element and binding the current center to it ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set the coordinates from the map center to the state of the map and then I pass it to the props of the marker.

```
  <Layer
          type="symbol"
          id="marker"
          layout={{
            'icon-image': 'icon',
          }}
        >
          <Marker anchor="bottom" coordinates={this.state.center} />
  </Layer>
```